# Downgrade setuptools from 20.10.1 to 18.2 on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, setuptools

I have following setup in my ubuntu virtual environment

> pip list
>   argparse (1.2.1)
>   pip (1.5.4)
>   setuptools (20.10.1)
>   wsgiref (0.1.2)

I want to install setuptools 18.2 as its a project requirement. Please advise how I can do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it, it looks like just doing `pip install setuptools==18.2` should do it.

```
$ pip install setuptools==20.10.1
You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting setuptools==20.10.1
  Using cached setuptools-20.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 15.0
    Uninstalling setuptools-15.0:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-15.0
Successfully installed setuptools-20.10.1

$ pip list
You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
pip (6.1.1)
setuptools (20.10.1)                                     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< look here

$ pip install setuptools==18.2
You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting setuptools==18.2
  Using cached setuptools-18.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 20.10.1
    Uninstalling setuptools-20.10.1:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-20.10.1
Successfully installed setuptools-18.2

$ pip list
You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
pip (6.1.1)
setuptools (18.2)                                         <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< look here
```